# Unable to retrieve an element through jQuery(idOfElement) when specifying name through a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript fails to access a JSF component by calling through its id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576258/javascript-fails-to-access-a-jsf-component-by-calling-through-its-id)

It does not work when I try to retrieve an element using `jQuery(idOfElement)` when I use a variable but works fine if I use something like this: `jQuery('#e')` . How can I make it work correctly by passing a variable parameter ?

I am trying out the following piece of  code:

```
function calculatePosition(idOfElement){
        var $element = jQuery(idOfElement);
        var offset = $element.offset();
        var x = offset.left;
        var y = offset.top;
        ....
        ....
    }
```

Comment: What is $elelemnt containing ? If you are passng "txtBox" in idOfElement what happens if you are explicit and call var $element = jQuery('#txtBox');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're passing in the `id` as a string like this:

`calculatePosition("randomID");`

Then you need to add the `#` at the start of the jQuery selector:

`var $element = jQuery("#" + idOfElement);`

Comment: tried doing this bt doesnt help

Comment: @Marcos - How are you calling the `calculatePosition` function?

Comment: I am calling it after an onclick event on a JSF component `<p:commandLink onclick="calculatePosition(this.id)" />`

Comment: but as I have checked out the function is called without any issues.

Comment: Put `alert(idOfElement);` as the first line in the function. What is alerted?

Comment: I can see the id of the element

Comment: Thanks for your effort! The problem has been solved it was due to some JSF issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576258/javascript-fails-to-access-a-jsf-component-by-calling-through-its-id

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
var $element = jQuery("#" + idOfElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you're not using an `id` selector, try using:

```
function calculatePosition(idOfElement){
        var $element = jQuery('#' + idOfElement);
        var offset = $element.offset();
        var x = offset.left;
        var y = offset.top;
        ....
        ....
    }
```